# configmap is not working for service and loadBalancerIP

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer, configmap

I'm used following kubernetes API. Configmap is not working with service and loadbalancer.

Here is code -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: Resource_group
    valueFrom :
      configMapKeyRef :
        name : app-configmap
        key : Resource_group
  name: appliance-ui
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: Static_public_ip
  valueFrom :
    configMapKeyRef :
      name : app-configmap
      key : Static_public_ip
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: appliance-ui
```

Here is error -

```
error: error validating "ab.yml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Service.metadata.annotations.valueFrom): invalid type for io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta.annotations: got "map", expected "string", ValidationError(Service.spec): unknown field "valueFrom" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServiceSpec]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

I have tried with --validate=false. It didn't work. Please let me know whether configmap will work for service and loadBalancerIP field or not.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? where is your kubernetes cluster being hosted? bare metal? config maps cant be used in services

Comment: You might need a tool like Helm or Kustomize to fill in these values at deployment time.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot configure a certain value for `Service` manifest through `configMapKeyRef`. AFAIK `ConfigMap` should mount to a Pod(container) for referring the values, so it does not allow other resource except Pod. Refer [Configure a Pod to Use a ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) or [ConfigMap and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#configmaps-and-pods) for more details.